# For loop for progressively adding string padding?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

So im pretty new to java, sorry if this is a bad question.

Im trying to use a for loop to continuously add padding to a string (in this case “*”), dependent on a user inputted value. So an 8 would give me:

```
*  --> no padding
 * --> printf("%2s", "*");
  * --> printf("%3s", "*");
   * --> etc.
    *
     *
      *
       * --> ending with the input -1 offset, so 7 in this case.
```

I don't know how to do this other than writing each statement out, but then its not using a for loop.This requires manual changing of the formatted string right?, not something that can be automatic?.

Comment: What do you mean `not something that can be automatic`? You can do it with a loop.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Is that why you need to use a for-loop?

Comment: I dont need to use a for loop. I just thought that would be the best option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the format dynamically as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How much padding do you want: ");
        int padding = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.printf("%" + padding + "s%n", "*");

        // A pattern using this trick
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%" + i + "s%n", "*");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How much padding do you want: 8
       *
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
        *
         *
```

Comment: In the for loop it should be I <= padding; You always do 10 iterations.

Comment: @Babi - The loop is for a different use case. It's not related to the value of `padding` you are getting from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```java
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            IntStream.range(0, i).forEach((c)->System.out.print(" "));
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Per each `i`, you are printing the `i` times empty strings padding, postfixed by `*`.

Change the characters (`" "` or `*`) with whatever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The "no padding" can be done using `printf("%1s", "*")`.

Now look at the first parameter to `printf` in all the calls. It's just a string, with an incrementing number from 1 to 8. So build that string using string-concatenation:

```java
printf("%" + i + "s", "*")  // if i is 1 to 8
```

```java
printf("%" + (i + 1) + "s", "*")  // if i is 0 to 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    System.out.println(" ".repeat(i) + "*");
```

output

```
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
       *
```